# Excel to Json File And Json to Excel In Specific Manner Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, excel, sheetjs

I have a Json Which look like

```
{
  "2001":{
    "abc":2000,
    "bcd":2005
  },
  "2002":{
    "abc":3000,
    "bcd":3500
  }
}
```

I want a specific way that converts this Json to excel file.
And When that excel file is again converted to Json it should give me above styled json again. Is there any way that I can convert this Json to excel and Excel to Json, but I won't want to change syntex of Json.While the Excel should also show every detail in Json have.

This line fetch data from excel sheet:

```
var rowMajor = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName], { raw: true, header: 1 });
```

I am thinking to fetch name of the sheet where the year is been set, and set it as a key to them by local concatenation. Multiple sheet has multiple data which would enclose as seen above in the question. But while reversing the thing 'Json to excel' I am not getting any idea how to do it by code, while the idea to do it is clear.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: var rowMajor = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName], { raw: true, header: 1 }); this line fetch data from excel sheet and I am thinking to fetch name of the sheet where the year is been set, and set it as a key to them by local concatenation. And multiple sheet has multiple data which would enclose as seen above in the question. But while reversing the thing 'Json to excel' I am not getting any idea how to do it by code, while the idea to do it is clear

Comment: Please add it to your question, not in the comments. Then we can delete these comments.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use **xlsx** library

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx
```

**Ex**:   XLSX.write(wb, {Props:{Author:"SheetJS"}});

> **wb**: is your data.
> and inside **{}** is your file name(**SheetJS** name of your file).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).